# Cannot install virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and kernel: 2.6.38-11-generic-pae. While using VirtualBox, i got this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and execute 'modprobe
>   vboxdrv' as root.

I tried to execute the command: sudo modprobe vboxdrv and got this error:

> FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.

After that, i execute this: sudo aptitude install virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms

```
duongnv@duongnv-laptop:~$ sudo aptitude install virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Writing extended state information... Done
Setting up virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms (3.1.6-dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing old virtualbox-ose-guest-3.1.6 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 3.1.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-ose-guest-3.1.6 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 2.6.38-11-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 2.6.38-11-generic-pae

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 2.6.38-11-generic-pae (i686)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose-guest/3.1.6/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms (3.1.6-dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing old virtualbox-ose-guest-3.1.6 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 3.1.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-ose-guest-3.1.6 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 2.6.38-11-generic-pae
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 2.6.38-11-generic-pae

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 2.6.38-11-generic-pae (i686)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox-ose-guest/3.1.6/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information       
Initializing package states... Done
```

Comment: Should we move all these to the Ubuntu Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Mikhail NO. Linux (including Ubuntu) questions are on topic and welcome here. Unless your comment was posted on [so] before migration, in which case, sorry :).

Comment: What does the `make.log` in the build directory say? Also, why are you using a 3-year old operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox: Odd behaviour after updating the host to OS X Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/733367/virtualbox-odd-behaviour-after-updating-the-host-to-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: I've just posted the solution that worked for me [here...](https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernel-module-ubuntu-18-04/1513506#1513506)

Answer (score 0):

Update your virtualbox package..

Chech this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1472391.html) for more details it is somewhat match to your proeblem.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.