# VirtualBox: Odd behaviour after updating the host to OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, osx-mavericks

I've just updated my Mac to OS X Mavericks. However, after doing so, I'm facing a couple of issues with my VirtualBox program including the following:

1 - The virtual machines (guest OSes) fail to load with the following error message:

**-Kernel driver not installed (rc= 1908); Make sure the kernel module has been loaded

  successfully**

I can solve this problem by the following command line from the terminal:

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

However, I have to do this every time my Mac starts up!

2 - The USB devices are no longer recognised (I've tried using a filter and also looking for the devices specifically, both didn't work).

3 - I can no longer mount shared folders through the guest (I cannot access shared host files from the guest virtual machine).

Any idea on how I can overcome these issues?

Comment: Reinstalling Virtualbox?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there no other way to fix these issues?

Comment: I have no idea. You asked this question 1 hour ago. In that time you could have tried reinstalling many times. It can be a quick solution. Reinstalling does not mean that you delete the local configuration, so you can keep all your settings. Reinstalling could result in restoring proper rights. Alternatively it could be in your settings in your homefolder. Then look for .Virtualbox or something and rename that, start Virtualbox and import the problematic VM. Then you know if it's configuration or install. I have Mavericks, and many others with me, and it should work normally.

Comment: I've just posted the solution that worked for me [here...](https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernel-module-ubuntu-18-04/1513506#1513506)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reinstalling is your best bet.

VirtualBox installs drivers in your host kernel that enable it to function. When your kernel is changed -- such as by an OS upgrade -- those drivers are in the old one, but not in the new one. The easiest way to get them into your new kernel is to reinstall VirtualBox, which conveniently will also repair anything else that may have been "damaged" during the OS upgrade.

As @rxt mentioned in his comment, reinstalling VirtualBox won't lose any of your settings or VMs. It's the most expedient route to repairing your issues and getting you running again.