# Running VirtualBox on Fedora

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, kernel

I am trying to install VirtualBox on fedora 23

When trying to start a VM I get the error "Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)"

My kernel version is 4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64

I have tried following a few guides online that suggest using Kmods or Akmod to install or build the necessary packages but neither is installed and dnf does not recognize them.

Does any one have an idea of how I can get the virtual box kernel drivers for my kernel?

Thanks

Comment: give a try `virt-manager`. It is opensource, tested and works well for my every-day work.

Comment: you need gcc kernel-devel and akmod-virtualbox, but as Jakuje said virt-manager is  proven to work out the box 'sudo dnf install @Virtualization'  then fire up virt-manager and done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox: Odd behaviour after updating the host to OS X Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/733367/virtualbox-odd-behaviour-after-updating-the-host-to-os-x-mavericks)