# VirtualBox: "Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)"

Tags: linux, virtualbox, drivers, virtual-machine, kernel

I'm trying to use VirtualBox (to run Outlook natively under Windows), but I keep having errors.

I initially had this very same error under Manjaro Linux, in which I could just install VirtualBox from the repos. As that failed (and I wanted to reinstall anyway), I have installed Fedora 28 and then installed VirtualBox from their download page on their own website. To my surprise I am getting the exact same error, and it's a stubborn one:

I can seemingly install VirtualBox (and Oracle extension) just fine, but whatever virtual machine I try to create, it will not start -- it *immediately* fails with the following error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing '/sbin/vboxconfig' as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

with a suggestion to run `/sbin/vboxconfig`, which I have of course done:

```
jgb@jgb-t450s:~$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig 
[sudo] password for jgb: 
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    kernel-devel kernel-devel-4.18.8-200.fc28.x86_64
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    kernel-devel kernel-devel-4.18.8-200.fc28.x86_64

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

I did as instructed:

```
jgb@jgb-t450s:~$ sudo yum install kernel-headers
Last metadata expiration check: 1:44:56 ago on 2018-09-25T09:45:21 CEST.
Package kernel-headers-4.18.9-200.fc28.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

and

```
jgb@jgb-t450s:~$ sudo yum install kernel-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:46:44 ago on 2018-09-25T09:45:21 CEST.
Package kernel-devel-4.18.9-200.fc28.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

but the `/sbin/vboxconfig` output remains the same.

I really don't know what more to try; I've never had problems with VirtualBox before.

Researching the issue shows me a lot of result from the past 15 years, including a [suggestion to install virt-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1046604/running-virtualbox-on-fedora#comment1465042_1046604) (which I didn't know of, and in which I can't figure out how to create a new VM), but I cannot seem to find an *actual solution*.

**Edit** - While I've tried the [gorka eguileor](https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux/) approach, [If Not True Then False](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) helped me either move on, or at least switch, to a different problem:

```
`RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)
supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.`
```

but that is another issue.

Comment: According to a few articles this can be caused by Secure boot. See: https://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux/

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox: Odd behaviour after updating the host to OS X Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/733367/virtualbox-odd-behaviour-after-updating-the-host-to-os-x-mavericks)