# Installing virtualbox on kali linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kernel, kali-linux

I am running kali linux 2017.3 4.13.10-1kali2. I have tried to install and run virtualbox to practice on some old OSs. problem is virtualbox always doesn't work no matter how much I try to install different and random old versions.

`Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.`

This is probably because my kernel doesn't work with the newest virtualbox version. So I tried to install older versions of vb but it's still the same. I think I know that if I upgraded kali linux to it's newest release it will most probably fix it all, But you guys have no idea about how slow my internet connection is. So, I am asking if there's a trick to download and install vb version that is specifically compatible with my my current kernel version (which is 4.13.10-1kali2)?

Comment: By default User in Kali is **Root** and one should not run virtualbox as root until he is prepared to welcome some serious issues with the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox: Odd behaviour after updating the host to OS X Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/733367/virtualbox-odd-behaviour-after-updating-the-host-to-os-x-mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

Kali is not a general purpose Linux distribution. It comes with a custom kernel and other tricks.

Did you read this page : https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux ?

Maybe should you go to another distribution ( e.g. multi-boot to a Linux Mint - also Debian-based or other general purpose one).