# vboxconfig fails for signed modules

Tags: virtualbox

In fedora 30 I signed the kernel modules for virtualbox (see e.g. [here](https://thomas-leister.de/fedora-secure-boot-kernelmodule-signieren) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernal-module-ubuntu-18-04)). After a modprobe for each of them I verify they have been loaded and then start a vboxconfig. That fails, however, and I cannot find out why.

All commands as root.

```
# lsmod | grep vbox
vboxpci                28672  0
vboxnetflt             32768  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxdrv               499712  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt

# /sbin/vboxconfig
MY_PATH="/usr/lib/virtualbox"
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: You must sign these kernel modules before using VirtualBox:
  vboxdrv vboxnetflt vboxnetadp vboxpci
See the documenatation for your Linux distribution..
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

# dmesg | tail -20
[20275.658123] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[20275.658412] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[20275.666192]  sda: sda1
[20275.667431] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[20275.929374] FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[20781.983099] sda: detected capacity change from 62109253632 to 0
[20785.288217] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[21014.468966] rfkill: input handler enabled
[21024.550884] rfkill: input handler disabled
[24065.704492] perf: interrupt took too long (3203 > 3165), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62000
[29997.822876] perf: interrupt took too long (4019 > 4003), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49000
[31001.218858] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[31001.223112] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
[31001.239256] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 1992006120 Hz
[31001.239257] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.0.12 (interface 0x00290008)
[33547.206587] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[33547.219277] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[33547.229107] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[33547.229111] vboxpci: IOMMU found
[33564.239275] VBoxPciLinuxLinuxUnload
```